# Special characters(á,é..ñ) in Bootsfaces not working

Tags: java, bootsfaces

I'm working in a jsf project using primefaces and we decided to integrate it with Bootsfaces due to their beautiful components, but when we try to type in a  something like '**José**', it will look correct initially, but after sending it to the database to be saved, it will save it as '**JosÃ©**'

All this special characters worked fine in primefaces components. Am i missing something in my configuration files? or is it a Bootsfaces issue.

```
<b:inputText label="Name" span="4" value="#{testBean.name}"/>
```

Comment: I have just saved and retrieved 'José' and some other special characters to a database and retrieved them and it works fine for me.  Can you perhaps give me a code example of how you are storing the data to the database?

Comment: As soon the value gets to the testBean, if i hit method save(), it will print the corrupted value.
    <b:commandButton look="primary" icon="floppy-disk" value="Save" 
             actionListener="#     {testBean.save()}"/>
    public void save(){
    System.out.println(name);
    }

Comment: Try using action instead of action listener.  And also are you not using ajax?   here is an example xhtml: `<h:form><b:inputText value="#{testBean.name}"/><b:commandButton action="#{testBean.save}" value="Save"><f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/></b:commandButton></h:form>` here is an example backing bean `@Named @ViewScoped public class TestBean { private String name; @PostConstruct public void onload() {name="José";} public String save() { System.out.println(name); return null;} //getters //setters }`

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, adding ajax <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/> fixed the issue. At first i wasn't using it because in my case the commandButton also redirected to a new page. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using action instead of action listener. And also are you not using ajax? here is an example xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <b:inputText value="#{testBean.name}"/>
    <b:commandButton action="#{testBean.save}" value="Save">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
    </b:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

here is an example backing bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onload() {
        name="José";
    }

    public String save() {
        System.out.println(name);
        return null;
    }

    //getters
    //setters
}
```